What is the correct way to get a column to take all available space in a grid?
This should be a simple thing I am missing so I apologize in advance. I have reusable view "TextRowView" that has 2 grid columns one will be a fixed width and the other I would like to take up all available space.
I don't understand why It displays correctly in the TruckView Preview but doesn't display correctly in the list view
struct TextRowView: View {
    
    let columns = [
        GridItem(.fixed(140), alignment: .leading),
        GridItem(.flexible(), alignment: .leading)
    ]
    
    let title: String
    let value: String
    
    var body: some View {
        LazyVGrid(columns: columns) {
            Text(title)
                .bold()
            
            Text(value)
        }
    }
}

Here is the cell for the list view
import SwiftUI

struct TruckView: View {
    
    let truck: Truck
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            TextRowView(title: "Year:", value: truck.year)
            
            TextRowView(title: "Make:", value: truck.make)
            
            TextRowView(title: "Model:", value: truck.model)
            
            TextRowView(title: "Driver:", value: truck.driver)
            
            TextRowView(title: "Truck #:", value: truck.truckNumber.formatted(.number.grouping(.never)))
        }
        .foregroundStyle(Color(hex: truck.foregroundColor))
        .padding()
        .background(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 10)
            .fill(Color(hex: truck.backgroundColor)))
    }
}

here is the list view
import SwiftUI

struct TripListView: View {
    
    @Environment(AppController.self) private var appController
    
    var body: some View {
        Group {
            List {
                ForEach(appController.filteredTrucks) { truck in
                    NavigationLink {
                        
                    } label: {
                        TruckView(truck: truck)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

Here is what it looks like in the simulator.

and this is the TruckView in the preview.

This appears to work but I am not sure if it is the correct / best way of handling this situation.
struct TextRowView: View {
    
    let columns = [
        GridItem(.fixed(140), alignment: .leading),
        GridItem(.flexible(minimum: UIScreen.main.bounds.width - 210), alignment: .leading)
    ]
    
    let title: String
    let value: String
    
    var body: some View {
        LazyVGrid(columns: columns) {
            Text(title)
                .bold()
            
            Text(value)
        }
    }
}

UPDATE: I was using this and was told a Grid would be better.
struct TextRowView: View {
    let title: String
    let value: String
    let width: CGFloat
    
    var body: some View {
        ViewThatFits(in: .horizontal) {
            LabeledContent {
                Text(value)
                    .frame(width: width, alignment: .leading)
            } label: {
                Text(title)
                    .bold()
            }
            
            VStack {
                Text(title)
                    .bold()
                
                Text(value)
                    .frame(width: width, alignment: .leading)
            }
        }
    }
}


Why multiple LazyVGrids? It seems like you have a fixed amount information to display, so there is little benefit by doing this lazily. If you want to use a grid, it should contain all the rows and columns, not one grid for each row.

@Sweeper I didn't think a LazyVGrid was needed and I am still trying to figure out Grids. I had a ViewThatFits and added that to the bottom of my question. I was getting help on a different part of the code and was told a grid would be better than a ViewThatFits and that I shouldn't use frames because it can cause other problems.

Who told you that? That claim needs some justification.

@Sweeper I don't remember his reason for that but it sounds like the way I was doing it before would work fine with all device sizes.

Since you are only displaying one row of details and the width of the first cell is fixed, it would be simpler to use an HStack in TextRowView instead:
// TextRowView

HStack {
    Text(title)
        .bold()
        .frame(maxWidth: 140, alignment: .leading)

    Text(value)
        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .leading)
}

Using a Grid only makes sense if there is more than one row. So if you really want to use a grid, I would suggest the following changes:

In TextRowView, remove the parent container. This way, the body function returns two "loose" views. This works, because View.body is implicitly a ViewBuilder.

Move the definition of columns from TextRowView to TruckView.

In TruckView, change the VStack to LazyVGrid and supply the columns that came from TextRowView.

Since the grid is shown in a List row, apply a frame with maxWidth: .infinity, so that it fills the full width of the row.


Here are the updated versions of these two views:
struct TextRowView: View {
    let title: String
    let value: String
    
    var body: some View {
        Text(title)
            .bold()
        Text(value)
    }
}

struct TruckView: View {
    let columns = [ //  moved from TextRowView
        GridItem(.fixed(140), alignment: .leading),
        GridItem(.flexible(), alignment: .leading)
    ]
    let truck: Truck

    var body: some View {
        LazyVGrid(columns: columns) { //  changed
            TextRowView(title: "Year:", value: truck.year)

            TextRowView(title: "Make:", value: truck.make)

            TextRowView(title: "Model:", value: truck.model)

            TextRowView(title: "Driver:", value: truck.driver)

            TextRowView(title: "Truck #:", value: truck.truckNumber.formatted(.number.grouping(.never)))
        }
        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity) //  added
        .foregroundStyle(Color(hex: truck.foregroundColor))
        .padding()
        .background(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 10)
            .fill(Color(hex: truck.backgroundColor)))
    }
}

Since TextRowView is now so trivial, you could replace it with a function in TruckView instead. The function needs to be annotated with @ViewBuilder:
@ViewBuilder
private func gridRow(title: String, value: String) -> some View {
    Text(title)
        .bold()
    Text(value)
}

LazyVGrid(columns: columns) {
    gridRow(title: "Year:", value: truck.year)

    // ... etc.
}


I was doing something similar to that and was told I would be better off using a Grid and to not use frames. I will edit the code to show the previous way at the bottom.

OK, answer updated to show how a grid could be used, if you really want to use one

Thank you! The HStack might be best for this situation but atleast I have a better understanding of Grids now.

If all you want is to show a label and a value, there is no need for a Grid or all this complexity, given that LabeledContent is available:
VStack {
    LabeledContent("Year:", value: "2015")
    LabeledContent("Make:", value: "Dodge")
    LabeledContent("Model:", value: "Ram")
    LabeledContent("Driver:", value: "John Doe")
    LabeledContent("Truck #:", value: "101")
}

If you need more control over alignment and other styling, just create a custom LabeledContentStyle
Here's a variety of options using LabeledContent:
import SwiftUI

struct TruckInfoRows: View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack (spacing: 15) {
            
            //Option 1
            VStack {
                LabeledContent("Year:", value: "2015")
                LabeledContent("Make:", value: "Dodge")
                LabeledContent("Model:", value: "Ram")
                LabeledContent("Driver:", value: "John Doe")
                LabeledContent("Truck #:", value: "101")
                
            }
            .stackBackground(.yellow)
            
            // Option 2 - with headers
            VStack {
                LabeledContent("Title", value: "Value")
                    .fontWeight(.bold)
                Divider()
                LabeledContent("Engine:", value: "HEMI")
                LabeledContent("Wheel size:", value: "20 in.")
                LabeledContent("Cylinders:", value: "V8")
            }
            .foregroundStyle(.black)
            .stackBackground(.cyan)
            
            
            //Option 3 - custom style, left aligned with separators
            VStack {
                LabeledContent("Year:", value: "2015")
                LabeledContent("Make:", value: "Dodge")
                LabeledContent("Model:", value: "Ram")
                LabeledContent("Driver:", value: "John Doe")
                LabeledContent("Truck #:", value: "115")
                    .labeledContentStyle(.alternate(valueColumnAlignment: .leading, showDivider: false))
            }
            .labeledContentStyle(.alternate(valueColumnAlignment: .leading, showDivider: true))
            .stackBackground(.teal)
            
            
            //Option 4 - custom style, center aligned
            HStack (spacing: 15) {
                
                VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                    LabeledContent("Year:", value: "2015")
                    LabeledContent("Make:", value: "Dodge")
                    LabeledContent("Model:", value: "Ram")
                    LabeledContent("Truck #:", value: "158")
                    
                }
                .labeledContentStyle(
                    .alternate(
                        fixedColumnWidth: 70,
                        fixedColumnAlignment: .trailing,
                        valueColumnAlignment: .leading,
                        columnSpacing: 10
                    )
                )
                .stackBackground(.green)
                
                VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                    LabeledContent("Year:", value: "2018")
                    LabeledContent("Make:", value: "GMC")
                    LabeledContent("Model:", value: "Jimmy")
                    LabeledContent("Truck #:", value: "245")
                    
                }
                .labeledContentStyle(
                    .alternate(
                        fixedColumnWidth: 70,
                        fixedColumnAlignment: .trailing,
                        valueColumnAlignment: .leading,
                        columnSpacing: 10
                    )
                )
                .stackBackground(.orange)
            }
        }
        .padding()

    }
}

struct CustomLabeledContentStyle: LabeledContentStyle {
    
    var fixedColumnWidth: CGFloat
    var fixedColumnAlignment: Alignment
    var valueColumnAlignment: Alignment
    var columnSpacing: CGFloat
    var showDivider: Bool
    
    func makeBody(configuration: Configuration) -> some View {
        HStack(spacing: columnSpacing) {
            configuration.label
                .frame(width: fixedColumnWidth, alignment: fixedColumnAlignment)
            configuration.content
                .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: valueColumnAlignment)
        }
        if showDivider {
            Divider()
                .padding(.bottom, 5)
        }
    }
}


extension LabeledContentStyle where Self == CustomLabeledContentStyle {
    static func alternate(
        fixedColumnWidth: CGFloat = 80,
        fixedColumnAlignment: Alignment = .leading,
        valueColumnAlignment: Alignment = .trailing,
        columnSpacing: CGFloat = 20,
        showDivider: Bool = false
    ) -> CustomLabeledContentStyle {
        
        CustomLabeledContentStyle(
            fixedColumnWidth: fixedColumnWidth,
            fixedColumnAlignment: fixedColumnAlignment,
            valueColumnAlignment: valueColumnAlignment,
            columnSpacing: columnSpacing,
            showDivider: showDivider
        )
    }
}

extension View {
    func stackBackground(_ color: Color = .secondary) -> some View {
        self
            .padding()
            .background(color.opacity(0.2), in: RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 10))
    }
}

#Preview {
    TruckInfoRows()
}


